# sigrok PulseView download location

Tags: download, logic, analyzer

I am trying to access https://sigrok.org/wiki/Downloads to download the PulseView GUI, but the website is down for some time now.

Would anyone have a fairly recent version to share please?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1):

A recent pulseview Windows build can be found here:
https://github.com/cleeus/pulseview-win-builds

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snapshot from Archive.org.

https://web.archive.org/web/20210410075147/https://sigrok.org/download/source/pulseview/

The Windows Installer is here:
https://web.archive.org/web/20201101141813/https://sigrok.org/jenkins/job/sigrok-cross-mingw/buildtype=static,debugtype=release,platform=cross-i686-w64-mingw32/lastSuccessfulBuild/artifact/pulseview-NIGHTLY-32bit-static-release-installer.exe

It appears to be down for me as well, hopefully it will be back soon.

Comment: Thanks @bigdutch, I managed to download the installer!